# How to hide or show buttons depends on clickable radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I just created 4 buttons(add, edit, delete, cancel) and a table with received data from ajax.

each row contains a radio(name:myRadio).

when a radio is clicked, the buttons should change their status (hide or show) depends on data fields( name: status) value. need your kind help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('data-field:idxRadio[name=myRadio]').change(function(row, value, index) {
    if (row.status === 'working') {
      $("#addBtn").show();
      $("#delBtn").hide();
    } else if (row.status === 'finished') {
      $("#delBtn").show();
      $("#addBtn").hide();
    } else {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-body">
  <div id="toolbar">
    <button type="button" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" id="editBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" id="delBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="del()">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" id="canBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="buttonSelection()">Cancel</button>
  </div>

  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="idxRadio" name="myRadio" data-valign="middle" data-align="center" data-radio="true"></th>
      <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-valign="middle" data-sortable="true" data-cell-style="cellStyle">No</th>
      <th data-field="keyPriority" data-align="center" data-valign="middle" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="linkFormat" data-cell-style="cellStyle">priority</th>
      <th data-field="endTime" data-align="center" data-valign="middle" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="timeFormat" data-cell-style="cellStyle">time</th>
      <th data-field="title" data-align="center" data-valign="middle" data-sortable="true" data-cell-style="cellStyle">title</th>
      <th data-field="status" data-align="center" data-valign="middle" data-sortable="true" data-cell-style="cellStyle">status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us an example with a filled table, the empty one will not help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a table with received data from ajax.

Then you need to use event delegation `on()` since the rows are added dynamically to the DOM, then you need to get the parent row `tr` when you click on a radio button using `.closest()` and then get the status from the last column (try to give it a class like `status` to simplify the find selector) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#table tbody').on('change', ':radio', function(value, index) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var status = row.find('.status').text().trim();

    switch (status) {
      case 'working':
        $("#addBtn").show();
        $("#delBtn").hide();
        break;
      case 'finished':
        $("#delBtn").show();
        $("#addBtn").hide();
        break;
      default:
        $('#toolbar button').show()
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Zakaria Acharki. the function works when I clicked my radio buttons. however when I created console.log(status) to see the value of status. it only contains empty space. any idea?

Comment: Make sure that every status columns has class `status`

Answer (score 0):

This is my worked codes.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#table tbody').on('change', ':radio', function(value, index) {

    var obj = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getSelections')[0];
    var status = obj.status;
    switch (status) {
        case 'wait':
            $("#addBtn").show();

            $("#delBtn").show();
            break;

        default:
        $('#addBtn').show()
    }

    });
});
```